# Javascript client for net.tcp connection?

Tags: javascript, tcpclient, webservice-client, nettcpbinding

Is there any way that I can write javascript that runs in the browser to create client code and connect to a net.tcp service endpoint and port?

For example, I know that a service contract is exposed at the endpoint https://www.demoexamplething.com:8001/service/mex (example), and is running on .NET server-side code (WCF or something else).  How can I use javascript to connect to this endpoint and use its web services?

I know that in a .NET project that I would simply create a "Connected Service" reference and auto-generate client code to work with requests and responses.  How can this be done in Javascript?

Comment: When you say client code, do you mean you're running this JavaScript in the browser?  Or a TCP client that runs server-side?  You can't make arbitrary TCP connections from within a browser, but there's also no reason to do so in this case... you can use the Fetch API for a web service.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way that I can write javascript that runs in the browser to create client code and connect to a net.tcp service endpoint and port?

No, you can't make arbitrary TCP connections from the browser, short of making a browser extension.

> For example, I know that a service contract is exposed at the endpoint...

For HTTP requests, you don't need to make a TCP connection.  You can use the Fetch API to make an HTTP request.  For example:

```
const res = await fetch('https://example.com');
const data = await res.text();
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

> I know that in a .NET project that I would simply create a "Connected Service" reference and auto-generate client code to work with requests and responses.

It's been a long time since I've messed with that... but wasn't there a WSDL or something that helped define the request/response data?  I bet someone has made a JavaScript module that wraps Fetch or XHR.  I wouldn't know specifically what to search for, but check over on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Comment: @gforce301 Thanks.  There's a WiFi antenna on the back.  Was going to mod an access point, with a directional antenna in the front for relaying a distant access point.  :-)